statistical test to see whether one group grew faster than the other
I have data on the number of enrollees in 2 groups from 2020-2023. Any statistical tests I can use to test whether the number of enrollees grew faster in group A compared to group B percentage wise? Like group A grew 527% 2023-2020 and group B only grew 13.6%
Group  Year  Number of enrollees
A      2020  51
A      2021  120
A      2022  260
A      2023  320
B      2020  1600
B      2021  1800
B      2022  2250
B      2023  2600


First, please decide how you measure growth, because you can obtain opposite answers: group A increased by less than B in numbers but more than B relatively.  In your example, once you have determined that, you likely won't need a test -- and no test will add any credence to the result because you have so few data and it would have to rely on additional assumptions.

That's a good question! I meant percentage!

I believe this can be done using a combination of nonlinear smooth effects from Generalized Additive Models (with the package {mgcv}) and targeted prediction-based comparisons using the package {marginaleffects}. The idea is to fit a GAM using a Poisson observation model with a log link function, which allows you to make inferences about multiplicative growth rates of the two yearly trends. There are several very useful families of functions in {marginaleffects} that make this possible, including the slopes() functions to compute growth rates and the hypotheses() function to perform hypothesis tests. Below I give a reproducible example using your supplied data, which I do not believe is too limited to make such comparisons meaningful. It clearly shows that group A grew faster, in relative terms, than group B. You could of course investigate variation in growth rates at specific points in time if you needed to, this is valid because the nonlinear smooth functions fitted in the GAM can be evaluated at any point in time.
# Load libraries
library(mgcv)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_classic())

# Construct data (use group_id rather than group, as this can cause conflicts with
# internal marginaleffects functions)
dat <- rbind(data.frame(year = 2020:2023,
                        group_id = 'A',
                        enrollees = c(51, 120, 260, 320)),
             data.frame(year = 2020:2023,
                        group_id = 'B',
                        enrollees = c(1600, 1800, 2250, 2600)))
dat$group_id <- as.factor(dat$group_id)

# Fit a GAM that allows the yearly smooth to vary among groups;
# use a Poisson observation model so that the link is a log, allowing for
# multiplicative (percentage) growth to be investigated
mod <- gam(enrollees ~ group_id + s(year, by = group_id, k = 3),
           data = dat,
           family = poisson())
summary(mod)
#> 
#> Family: poisson 
#> Link function: log 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> enrollees ~ group_id + s(year, by = group_id, k = 3)
#> 
#> Parametric coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  5.01087    0.04672  107.26   <2e-16 ***
#> group_idB    2.60310    0.04804   54.18   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#>                     edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
#> s(year):group_idA 1.949  1.997  202.9  <2e-16 ***
#> s(year):group_idB 1.000  1.000  286.2  <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> R-sq.(adj) =  0.998   Deviance explained = 99.9%
#> UBRE = 0.90722  Scale est. = 1         n = 8

# Plot predictions on the response scale
plot_predictions(mod, condition = c('year', 'group_id'),
                 points = 0.5)


# Plot predictions on the link (log) scale
plot_predictions(mod, condition = c('year', 'group_id'),
                 type = 'link')


# Plot slopes (growth rates) on the log scale
plot_slopes(mod, condition = c('year', 'group_id'), 
            variables = 'year',
            type = 'link')


# Plot average slopes (growth rates) on the log scale
plot_slopes(mod, variables = 'year', by = 'group_id',
            type = 'link')


# Are these 'significantly' different?
hypotheses(slopes(mod, variables = 'year', by = 'group_id',
                  type = 'link'),
           hypothesis = 'pairwise')
#> 
#>   Term Estimate Std. Error   z Pr(>|z|)    S 2.5 % 97.5 %
#>  A - B    0.467     0.0472 9.9   <0.001 74.4 0.375  0.559
#> 
#> Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
#> Type:  link

Created on 2024-05-22 with reprex v2.0.2
